Clicking HTML table row button opens forms for every single row
Beginner here. I have an HTML table with buttons and I want a button to toggle open a form with the values from that row. The problem is, if I have multiple rows in my table, it opens multiple forms for each row with the values pre-filled. How can I make it so that it only opens a single form for that row only?
My HTML and JS, shortened for clarity
I have already gone from IDs to classes, but it still wouldn't work.


$(".btn-edit-address").click(function() {
  $('.form-edit-address').toggle('fast');
});

function closeEditAddressForm() {
  $('.form-edit-address').toggle('fast');
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive my-5">
  <table id="table-address-book" class="display table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr style="text-align: center;">
        <th style="width: 150px;">insert headers here</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for address in addressInfo %}
      <tr class="row-address-book" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
        <td>
          insert table data here
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="display: inline; vertical-align: baseline;">
            <button class="btn btn-sm mx-1 btn-black" type="button" hidden="">
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                        </button>
            <button class="btn-edit-address btn btn-sm mx-1" type="button" style="color: rgb(24, 115, 184);">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        </button>
            <form action="{{ url_for('homepage.deleteBuyerAddress', addressBookID=address.0 ) }}" class="form-delete-address" method="POST">
              <button class="btn-delete-address btn btn-sm mx-1" type="submit" style="color: red;">
                                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                            </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

{% for address in addressInfo %}
<form action="#" method="POST" class="form-edit-address" style="display: none; margin-top: 50px;">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    input groups here
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary me-2" type="submit" style="margin-top: 25px;">
        Edit address
        </button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning ms-2" type="button" style="margin-top: 25px;" onclick="closeEditAddressForm()">
        Cancel
        </button>
  </div>
</form>
{% endfor %}




I think sticking to IDs would be better option here. Because the problem you are right now facing is that you are calling $('.form-edit-address').toggle('fast'); which corresponds to all the forms created in the webpage. So, all the forms are toggled. Classes are generally used to apply styling to all elements. On the other hand IDs are used to uniquely identify elements. IDs are and must be unique. So, using IDs will solve your problem.

This is not a python issue. Please change the snippet I made you to a [mcve] with two rows.

You can delegate and have only one form
Store the ID in the row as a data attribute and use that to tell the server what ID you are targeting


$(".row-address-book .btn").on("click", function() {
  const $tgt = $(this).closest('.btn'); // did we click a button?
  if ($tgt.length === 0) return; // no, leave
  const $row = $tgt.closest('tr');
  const $form = $('.form-edit-address');
  $form.find('[name=id]').val($row.data('id')); // add the ID to the form
  const $formButton = $form.find('[type=submit]');
  $input = $('div.input-group');
  const html = $row.find('.address').clone().html();
  $input.html(html); // copy contents
  if ($tgt.is('.btn-edit-address')) {
    $input.find('input').each(function() {
      $(this).removeAttr('readonly')
      $formButton.text('Submit')
    });
  } else if ($tgt.is('.btn-delete-address')) {
    $formButton.text('Delete')
    $form.attr('action', '{{homepage.deleteBuyerAddress}}');
  }
  $form.show('fast');
});
$('.closeEdit').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('form').hide()
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.7.1/css/all.min.css" />
<div class="table-responsive my-5">
  <table id="table-address-book" class="display table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr style="text-align: center;">
        <th style="width: 150px;">insert headers here</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row-address-book" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" data-id="idforrow1">
        <td class="address">
          <input type="text" name="add1" value="row 1 addressline1" readonly /><br />
          <input type="text" name="add1" value="row 1 addressline2" readonly /><br />
          <input type="text" name="add1" value="row 1 addressline3" readonly /><br />
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="display: inline; vertical-align: baseline;">
            <button class="btn btn-sm mx-1 btn-black" type="button" hidden="">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
              </button>
            <button class="btn-edit-address btn btn-sm mx-1" type="button" style="color: rgb(24, 115, 184);">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
              </button>
            <button class="btn-delete-address btn btn-sm mx-1" type="button" style="color: red;">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
              </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row-address-book" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" data-id="idforrow1">
        <td class="address">
          <input type="text" name="add2" value="row 2 addressline1" readonly /><br />
          <input type="text" name="add2" value="row 2 addressline2" readonly /><br />
          <input type="text" name="add2" value="row 2 addressline3" readonly /><br />
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="display: inline; vertical-align: baseline;">
            <button class="btn btn-sm mx-1 btn-black" type="button" hidden="">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
              </button>
            <button class="btn-edit-address btn btn-sm mx-1" type="button" style="color: rgb(24, 115, 184);">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
              </button>
            <button class="btn-delete-address btn btn-sm mx-1" type="button" style="color: red;">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
              </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<form action="#" method="POST" class="form-edit-address" style="display: none; margin-top: 50px;">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    input groups here
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary me-2" type="submit" style="margin-top: 25px;">
      Save address
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning ms-2 closeEdit" type="button" style="margin-top: 25px;">
      Cancel
    </button>
  </div>
</form>




With your current structure, it seems that you'll need a way to associate each table row (or button) with its corresponding form. It looks like each row has the same numeric index as its form (i.e. row#1 corresponds to form#1, row#2 to form#2, etc.), so you might consider using jQuery's index() and eq(). You could also assign each table row (or button) a data attribute that matches the data attribute or unique ID of its corresponding form.
Here's an example using index() and eq():


// define all forms
let $forms = jQuery('.form');

jQuery('.cell').on('click', function() {

  // define this row's numeric index in the table
  let indx = jQuery(this).parent('tr').index();

  // hide all forms
  $forms.hide(200);

  // show the form that corresponds with the table row
  $forms.eq(indx).show(200);

});
table {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.cell {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form {
  display: none;
  color:green;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell">One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell">Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell">Three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<form class="form">
  One!
</form>
<form class="form">
  Two!
</form>
<form class="form">
  Three!
</form>



Here's an example using data attributes and IDs:


// define all forms
let $forms = jQuery('.form');

jQuery('.cell').on('click', function() {

  // get the data attribute from the clicked table cell
  let id = jQuery(this).data('id');

  // hide all forms
  $forms.hide(200);

  // show the form with the ID matching that of the clicked table cell
  jQuery('#form-' + id).show(200);

});
table {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.cell {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form {
  display: none;
  color: green;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell" data-id="1">One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell" data-id="2">Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell" data-id="3">Three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<form class="form" id="form-1">
  One!
</form>
<form class="form" id="form-2">
  Two!
</form>
<form class="form" id="form-3">
  Three!
</form>



